# Crontab No Longer Runs Raspberry Pi Python Script in Background But Still Runs Manually

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi2

I am able to run my Python script in the background to control two servos by automatically launching the script at boot up using sudo crontab -e. I modified the script so I am now continually writing the servos current position to a horz.txt and vert.txt file and using those files to initialize the steppers to their home position so I can find home position again after a power loss. The script works fine with the horz.txt and vert.txt code that I added when I manually launch the script from the command line on the black screen using sudo python mystepper6.py, but it doesn't launch automatically at startup nor does it show up as running when I type ps ax on the command line. I added a little extra code just to wiggle the servos before the main program starts and and the servos automatically wiggle as programmed in the sudo crontab -e but then it just stops and won't continue to find the home position. It seems to be something with the new code but I don't know what it could be. My sudo crontab -e line is @reboot (sleep2;python /home/pi/mystepper6.py) &. Below is the script for mystepper6.py.

The script below was shortened to show the relevant lines due to limited space available in this post. The sudo reboot hangs with no error message near the bottom where it is commented 'move to home position' (it doesn't move). I am able to print adjustv and adjusth integers prior to that point so the variables are properly assigned a value from the .txt files at that point. When I manually run mystepper6.py from the command line it runs perfectly.

I have spent waaay too many hours on this problem and have purchased two e-books to no avail. Please help.

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio         # import library RPi.GPIO gpio=use general          purpose input output pin names
import time                             # import time library

PINSh = [27,10,18,23]           # variable 'PINS' holds a list of gpio pin numbers
SEQAh = [(27,),(10,),(18,),(23,)]
PINSv = [4,17,22,24]            # variable 'PINS' holds a list of gpio pin numbers
SEQAv = [(4,),(17,),(22,),(24,)]

DELAY = 0.01                            # time between motor steps (too small of a number then the motor stalls)
alpha = 140                             # horizontal full scale viewing angle in motor counts 128 counts = 360 degrees
beta = 30                               # was 15 vertical full scale viewing angle in motor counts 128 counts = 360 degrees

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)          # tells RPi.GPIO we want to use pin names (BCM is the mfg)
for pin in PINSh:           # pin is a variable name assigned a new value each loop; PINS is a list
    gpio.setup(pin, gpio.OUT)       # this says we want to use 'pin' as an output

for pin in PINSv:           # pin is a variable name assigned a new value   each loop; PINS is a list
    gpio.setup(pin, gpio.OUT)

def stepper(sequence, pins):        # def says 'stepper' is the function name (like a variable), then parameters are inside ()
    for step in sequence:
        for pin in pins:
            if pin in step:
                gpio.output(pin, gpio.HIGH)
            else:
                gpio.output(pin, gpio.LOW)

webcam_horz_home = open("horz.txt", "a")  
webcam_horz_home.close()                  
webcam_vert_home = open("vert.txt", "a")
webcam_vert_home.close()

#  load last position prior to power down

webcam_horz_home = open("horz.txt", "r")
rows = webcam_horz_home.readlines();
for row in rows:
    adjusth = int(row)
webcam_horz_home.close()

webcam_vert_home = open("vert.txt", "r")
rows = webcam_vert_home.readlines();
for row in rows:
    adjustv = int(row)
webcam_vert_home.close()                
counter = 0               #   move to home position
while counter < adjustv:                               
    stepper(SEQAv, PINSv)                              
    counter = counter + 1
# CONTINUAL PAN AND TILT OPERATION (box pattern):
```

Comment: My crontab -e line is @reboot (sleep2;python /home/pi/mystepper6.py) &

Comment: What if you try `sudo chmod +x your_script` and add the script to root's crontab via `sudo crontab -e`? Write out the full paths from root to file in the crontab. There can also be issues with the `@reboot` directive (I've read quite a few complaints about that particular cron feature)

Comment: jDo, Just tried your suggestion as follows: @reboot (sleep2;sudo chmod +x python /home/pi/mystepper6.py) & from the sudo crontab -e and got the same problem. Did I input your suggestion correctly?

Comment: You need to add a space between `sleep` and `2` and you only need to run `sudo chmod +x some_script` once to set the executable bit on your script (which allows it to be executed). No need to have that command in the cron entry

Comment: jDo, my sudo crontab -e now looks like: @reboot (sleep 2; python /home/pi/mystepper6.py) &; from the command line I executed sudo chmod +x /home/pi/mystepper6.py and sudo chmod +x mystepper6.py and still have the same problem after sudo reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this on my Pi running Raspbian and it worked.

First, I created a python script called some_script.py in the primary user's home directory. 
Script contents:

```
import sys
import time

with open("/home/username/some_script.py.out", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(time.time()) + " " + "some_script.py RAN!\n")
```

Then, in the terminal, I set the executable bit on the file which allows it be executed:

```
sudo chmod +x some_script.py
```

Then, also in the terminal, I typed `sudo crontab -e` and added the following line at the bottom of the `root` user's crontab:

```
@reboot sleep 2; /usr/bin/python /home/username/some_script.py
```

I then rebooted, `cd`ed to `/home/username/` and confirmed that python had run at reboot and written to a file:

```
cat some_script.py.out 
1458062009.53 some_script.py RAN!
```

**UPDATE / SOLUTION**

After confirming that the OP was able to successfully replicate the steps above, I was fairly confident that this was not an issue stemming from varying implementations of cron on different *nix systems or some other edge case. As expected, he could run python via cron, he could use the `@reboot` feature and he could write to disk without any sort of permission issues.

However, it still didn't work. What *did* solve the issue was simply to use absolute paths rather than relative paths.

Changing

```
webcam_horz_home = open("horz.txt", "a")
```

to

```
webcam_horz_home = open("/home/pi/horz.txt", "a")
```

and

```
webcam_vert_home = open("vert.txt", "a")
```

to

```
webcam_vert_home = open("/home/pi/vert.txt", "a")
```

got OP's steppers purring again :)

**EXPLANATION / BACKGROUND**

When executing scripts or commands via the crontab of other users (in this case `root`), paths relative to the regular user's home directory (eg. `~/.bashrc`) will no longer be valid or will point to a different file with the same filename if it exists. The same "issue" is sometimes seen when people run servers that call scripting languages such as PHP (often executed by the `www-data` user).

On a Raspberry Pi, these things can cause a bit of a catch-22 when working with GPIOs because the GPIO device is locked down and not accessible to unprivileged users without a change of permissions and groups.

If OP ran his script as `root` by adding the cron entry via `sudo crontab -e`, he would have access to the GPIO device (since `root` has access to almost everything). However, the relative paths in his python script that implicitly reference the home folder of the non-privileged user `pi` would no longer be valid (since `home` now means the folder `/root` which is the home folder of the `root` user).

If OP ran his scripts via the non-privileged `pi` user's crontab by adding the cron entries via `crontab -e` (without `sudo`), the paths would be valid (`home` or `~/` would now mean `/home/pi/`) but then he wouldn't have access to the GPIO device since `pi` is pretty unprivileged. Note: the `@reboot` feature is not available in all cron implementations (some embedded and stripped down *nix distros don't have it) and often it doesn't work for users other than `root`.

This means that OP had two options (there might be more; i'm no Linux guru):

1. place the files `vert.txt` and `horz.txt` in the home folder of the `root` user.
2. simply change the paths specified in the python script and keep running the script @reboot in `root`'s crontab.

No. 2 is probably better since it keeps the home folder of `root` empty and keeps OP's files in `pi`'s home folder. `root` should generally not be messed with unless there's no other options such as using `sudo`.

Comment: jDo, I thank you very much for your efforts but I still cant get it to run. I had a very similar script that did run; I was using photo sensors to find home for the web cam on that one. I modified that script to record stepper motor position, it runs manually fine, but cant get it to run from crontab. I have done everything I know to try to find out why it is hanging up but am obviously stuck. I retyped the entire code at least twice with no improvement and re-tried the old code and it works.

Comment: Try doing exactly what I did and see if it creates the file `/home/username/some_script.py.out` . Create the same script, make it executable with chmod, add to crontab etc.

Comment: Ok, I will try it. If it takes me a bit, I have a meeting in about 15 minutes that might take me 45 minutes.

Comment: I tried the code provided and could not get it to work. I rebooted and went to the command screen and just saw the blinking cursor. When I ran sudo python some_script.py it just returned me back to the blinking cursor.

Comment: I do see "1458073292.94 some_script.py RAN!" in the some_script.py.out  file though which is located in /home/pi.

Comment: @Mark Ah! Great. Then it worked. Now try changing `@reboot sleep 2; /usr/bin/python /home/username/some_script.py` to `@reboot sleep 2; /usr/bin/python /home/pi/folder_name/script_name.py` replacing `/home/pi/folder_name/script_name.py` with the path/name of your python script

Comment: I forgot to mention. When you run stuff via cron, you're not running as your own user. The same goes for web servers, PHP and the like. Often, everything will run as root or www-data. This means that this line `webcam_horz_home = open("horz.txt", "r")` will not make sense if your script is called by root - unless you place the file in `/root/` which is the root user's home folder. Change `webcam_horz_home = open("horz.txt", "r")` to `webcam_horz_home = open("/absolute/path/to/horz.txt", "r")` and do the same for all other files opened by your python script (vert.txt)

Comment: Ok, that sounds interesting. I will try that. I currently have the files located in /home/pi/mystepper.py, /home/pi/horz.txt and /home/pi/vert.txt (I am not far enough along to have extra folders yet, just a newbee). Where do I need to move them to?  And is /home/pi/horz.txt the absolute path that you referenced? I just do this for horz.txt and vert.txt, right? This sounds like it might just do the trick! Thanks! I will let you know for sure.

Comment: Yep, just keep your files in their current locations, don't do anything to the `/root` folder and edit your python script so it only uses the absolute paths to your files. `webcam_horz_home = open("horz.txt", "a")` should be changed to `webcam_horz_home = open("/home/pi/horz.txt", "a")` and so on.

Comment: BINGO!!!! That was the magic I needed. Thank you so much! You don't know the smile that went on my face after sudo reboot and then to hear the sound of those stepper motors once again! That was my aHa moment for the week.

Comment: I am new to this site so if you can tell me how to vote you up or increase your status, I will be glad to do so.

Comment: @jDo I'd suggest editing into your answer the details about what user cron tasks are run as seeing as that appears to be what solved the OP's problem.

Comment: @Mark That's great! :) Glad to hear it worked. I'm pretty new here as well and mainly signed up to learn and solve problems (some play sudoku, I try to answer questions on SO). By the way, I think you just gave me some internet points simply by accepting my answer. (@FGreg) I'll edit the answer so it contains the actual solution; just in case someone else comes along and has the same problem.